# I get a null class with NSClassFromString

Tags: objective-c

I have the same code shared by 2 apps, and depending on the current app a different class is used.

className is the string which can be "PrefixClass1" or "PrefixClass2" (and it is correct for both apps, I've checked in the debugger).

However currentClass is null for app2. (It perfectly works for app1)

```
NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Prefix%@", [[NSApp delegate] applicationName]];
Class currentClass = NSClassFromString(className);
```

This means is null right ? http://cl.ly/AYSn

thanks

Comment: did you import the header of class2?

Comment: @d.lebedev I don't see any header imported, I don't see the header of class1 as well. Maybe I should check the superclasses, but I don't think I will find them because I'm in the base code (without app-specific classes).

Comment: By the way, is there a way to see all imported headers from all superclasses of a specific class in the compiler ? Or I have to search for them manually ?

Comment: Probably you have to search manually

Comment: @d.lebedev I've searched for #import "class1.h" and #import "class2.h". There are no such lines (of course, beside the respective implementation files. But class1 works, so it seems that it isn't necessary to import the header of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by adding the .m file to the target > Compile Sources... Since I had many targets, xCode didn't know where to put it.

Answer (score 2):

1.) check you are really using the right class name and NSString (@"class2" Syntax)

2.) add the "-all_load" linker flag to your build settings (if linker finds no references, the class might not be loaded into the runtime)

Comment: The string is correct. I've checked it. And it is the same code for both apps which is creating the string (just the line above the line I've posted.

Comment: Also, I've added the flag you suggests without success.. the class is null: http://cl.ly/AZF8

Comment: what does a hardcoded `[PrefixClass2 class]` return? and if it returns an object, does NSClassFromString also return a value?

Comment: I've solved by adding the new PrefixClass2.m file to the target > Compile Sources.

Comment: Honestly I'm a bit disappointed, because  cleaning the built, removing the built folders didn't solve the problem. I had to manually add the new .m file to the Compile Sources. And the reason probably is that I've dragged it from desktop. Could you confirm this ?

Comment: So, everytime I import a source file (by dragging it from Finder, I have then to import it to compile sources ? I thought xCode was doing this for me...